# Clarion Topspeed database scanner Mass update

Tags: clarion

I need to update a column in a Clarion Topspeed (TPS) file based on the value in another column `update table set subnumber = 20 where reference1='DC'`.

The Topspeed Database Scanner has a Mass Update function on the File menu, but I cannot get it to work.  I don't have access to the ODBC driver or the Clarion programming environment. Link: [Mass Update Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWRg7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

it's quite easy when you try few times :-) ... so, this is how you can do it: liek you said, open file->mass update ... on field subnumber in the second column you click on arrow on the right, to enter in the window where you can define formula ...

in your case you can use: CHOOSE(REFERENCE1='DC', 20, SUBNUMBER)

which means that the value od subnumber will be 20 for every reference1 is 'DC', otherwise put the same value into the subnumber again ... after you press apply don't forget to refresh with f5 ...

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not sensitive, I can update the file for you.
Without the odbc the mass update is your only option, copy the file to a separate folder and try to update if from there, someone may have a record lock on the tabel

Comment: Thank you, I have actually edited all 2500 records manually in Topspeed Database Scanner.